# How to remove NULL and empty for a particular column in DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to remove records from a dataframe having demo_name as NULL and demo_name as empty.

demo_name is a column in that dataFrame with String datatype

I am trying the below code . I want to apply trim as there are records for demo_name with multiple spaces.

```
   val filterDF = demoDF.filter($"demo_name".isNotNull && $"demo_name".trim != "" )
```

But I get error as cannot resolve symbol trim

Could someone help me to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `trim` as if you are acting on a `String`, but the `$` function uses `implicit` conversion to convert the name of the column to the `Column` instance itself. The problem is that `Column` doesn't have a `trim` function.

You need to import the library functions and apply them to your column:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

demoDF.filter($"demo_name".isNotNull && length(trim($"demo_name")) > 0)
```

Here I use the library functions `trim` and `length`--`trim` to strip the spaces of course and then `length` to verify that the result has anything in it.

Comment: Glad to help. Please upvote and accept so other people can benefit as well.