# Using Java, drop blank record (with null AND all type of blanks) from a Spark dataframe

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I say all types of blanks, I mean a blank or a whitespace blank. So this string can be empty, or it can have a blank space, or two blank spaces, etc. I would consider those all blanks and I need them removed from my dataframe. So far I have:

```
Dataset<Row> dayCustAcctCardJoinCustDF = dayCustAcctCard
  .filter(dayCustAcctCard.col(custJoinKey).isNotNull())
  .select(acctJoinKey, custJoinKey);
```

This is just removing nulls from the original dataframe. I'm looking to enhance that filter to remove and records who have a custJoinKey value of a blank value or a 1 character length white space, 2 character length blank space, etc.

Comment: I think an example of the dayCustAcctCard and its schema would help to answer you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove NULL and empty for a particular column in DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43306840/how-to-remove-null-and-empty-for-a-particular-column-in-dataframe)

Comment: If I understand correctly, and you want to remove fields that are only whitespaces, can you use the trim function (`org.apache.spark.sql.functions.trim`) to reduce the "blanks" to 0 length, and then use `filter` to keep only nonzero length records (using `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.length`)?  It works in scala, and although I haven't tried it in Java, the API has the necessary functions.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. Thanks!!